# How to correctly calculate partitions for apoc.cypher.mapParallel2 based on CPU characteristics

Tags: neo4j, cpu, apoc, apoc-extended

Let's say I have a CPU with `24 cores`/`48 threads`.

I would like to correctly specify the `partitions` parameter to `apoc.cypher.mapParallel2` procedure https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/5/overview/apoc.cypher/apoc.cypher.mapParallel2/.

How to calculate `partitions` parameter value based on CPU charcteristcs ?